# Optimizing front-end loading through this technique

Tags: css, django, optimization, frontend

I was reading about facebook's pageltes and [Quora's Faster Paint](https://engineering.quora.com/Faster-Paint-Times).

The best I understood is:

1. start sending as soon as possible (chunked transfer)
2. send basic layout of page first with inline css and page divisions in 
   form of 'pagelets'
3. keep filling these pagelets (along with css) as response is fetched
4. and then download scripts and other resources.

This approach seems efficient. What more could be added/ omitted in this?

I understand this is broad but How can such a thing be implemented?

do we need to send streaming response for this?

and how does the front-end handle response?

would be grateful if you can also share some articles to read further.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately this question is way too broad for StackOverflow. See guidelines on asking questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @deiga I understand that, would be glad if someone can share great, pragmatic articles for same

Answer (score 1):

Front-end optimization Tips to improve web performance.

There are millions of websites accessed everyday for variety of reasons. 
  Unfortunately many of the websites are poorly optimized.

-poorly optimized websites are plagued with a variety of issues with slow 
        loading times, browser incompatiblity.

The below mentioned techniques will help you to  improve front end 
   optimizations.

Clean up Html document, strive to write in a manner that is both concise and 
   effective.

->proper css placement.
     Put all your external style sheets at the top of your Html documents header 
     in order to ensure progressive rendering.

```
<head><link href='https://yourwebsite.com/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet'type='text/css'></head>
```

Proper Javascript Placement

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   < =========== >

<!-- For laoding js related files -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionaly when using javascript you should always prefer "async" script loading. This will prevent any  tags from blocking the html rendering process in the event that it does come across one in the middle of the document for instance.

```
<script src="demo_defer.js" async></script>
```

> What Is an Async Script?
>   Loading scripts using async (AKA
>   asynchronous) means that the loading process of your scripts will not
>   interrupt the rendering of your webpage. This allows your web page to
>   render more quickly as parsing is not paused every time a script must
>   be loaded. This also allows for multiple scripts to be loaded
>   concurrently which is beneficial given that one script does not depend
>   on another.

Differences Between Synchronous and Asynchronous loading??

Synchronous script loading works in the following way:

- HTML parsing is paused when it encounters a  tag which loads
  synchronously
- A request is made to fetch the file (if external)
- The    script is    downloaded and executed immediately HTML parsing
  resumes

async script loading works like so:

- HTML parsing continues as it encounters a  tag which loads asynchronously
- A request is made to fetch the file (if external)
- The script is downloaded in the background and executed upon completion.

Minify CSS, JS and HTML

Minification techniques can help you to eliminate unnecessary characters within a file. When you are writing code in an editor, you likely use indentations,comments. These methods are best practice to certainly keep your code clean and readable, but they also add extra bytes to your document.

For example check with the below css code before minification is applied, where you notice extra space, indentations& comments.

```
.navbar-default{
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right,#dd4959, #852742 );  /* 
  Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#dd4959, #852742); /* W3C, IE 10+/ 
  Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ *
       }
  #menu {
       border-radius: NaNpx;
       margin-top: 69px;
       margin-left: 66px;
       margin-bottom: 48px;
       background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right,#dd4959, #b852742 );  /* 
       Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
       background: linear-gradient(to right,#dd4959, #852742); /* W3C, IE 
       10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
        }
       #form{
          /* fallback for old browsers */
          background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right,#dd4959, #852742 );  
         /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
          background: linear-gradient(to right,#dd4959, #852742); /* W3C, IE 
          10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
          padding-top: 10px;
           padding-left: 120px;
           }
           #form h1 {
           color: white;
           font-family: 'Poppins';
           font-size: 60px;
            margin-left: 11px;
                }
```

And here is the same snippet after minification has been applied.

```
.navbar-default{border-radius:0;
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(toright,#dd4959,#852742);
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#dd4959,#852742);
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#dd4959,#852742)}
#form{background:-webkit-linear-gradient(to right,#dd4959,#852742);
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#dd4959,#852742);
  padding-top:10px;padding-left:120px}
#form h1{color:white;font-family:'Poppins';
  font-size:60px;margin-left:11px}
```

> > - Increase Speed With a CDN and Caching.  The CDN allows your site’s visitors to load data from their nearest server. If you use a CDN,
> >       your site’s files will automatically be compressed for rapid delivery
> >       across the globe.

- Compress Your Files.

> While many CDN services will compress your files for you, if you don’t
>   use a CDN consider using a file compression method on your origin
>   server to improve your front end optimization. File compression will
>   make your site’s content light and easy to manage. One of the most
>   commonly used file compression methods is Gzip. This is an excellent
>   method for shrinking documents, audio files, PNG images, and other
>   bulky files that have not already been compressed.
>
> Brotli is another file compression algorithm that is still fairly new,
>   however growing in popularity. This open-source algorithm is regularly
>   updated by software engineers from Google and other organizations. It
>   has proven itself to compress files at a much better ratio than other
>   existing methods. Although support for this algorithm is still minimal
>   it is well positioned to be the next default file compression
>   algorithm.

- Optimize Your Images

> For people who are unaccustomed to the ways of front end optimization,
>   images can be a website-killer. Massive photo albums and large
>   high-resolution images on your site can jam the rendering process.
>   High-definition images that are not optimized can weigh several
>   megabytes. Therefore, properly optimizing these will allow you to
>   improve your site’s front end performance.